# Dynamic Current Month and year for SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need dynamic date for current month, which will automatic update for each month instead of writing full date like (between '5/1/2022' and '5/31/2022'). My current query

```
Select TDate, sum(CustSales) As 'Total Sales'
From SalesTra
Where TDate between '5/1/2022' and '5/31/2022'
Group by TDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select TDate, sum(CustSales) As 'Total Sales'
From SalesTra
Where TDate between (DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) and (DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(GETDATE()), -1))
Group by TDate
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` is rarely the correct choice to use when working with dates; especially if they have a time portion. As an example `2022-06-30T12:34:44` is *not* `BETWEEN '20220601' AND '20220630'` You are far better off using boundaries with `>=` and `<` logic.